# How do I get the difference between two FIFO array states?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-difference

I have two arrays that represent a fifo-like state, an old state and a new state. I need a function that finds the newly added items by comparing the new array with the old one. Below 3 examples of two arrays where 1 has items added to the front of it compared to the other:

```js
// Input 1
const arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'];
const arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']; // added 'a' and 'b' in front
// Input 2
const arr3 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'];
const arr4 = ['q', 'r', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']; // added 'q' and 'r' in front
// Input 3
const arr5 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'];
const arr6 = ['a', 'b', 'q', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']; // added 'a' 'b' and 'q' in front
// New Input 4
const arr7 = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
const arr8 = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']; // added 'a' and 'b'  in front
```

Note that the amount of newly added items is removed from the back of the array.
Here the desired functionality `getItemsAdded(arr1, arr2)` function:

```
// Desired output for 'getItemsAdded()' function
console.log(getItemsAdded(arr1, arr2)); // [ 'a', 'b' ]
console.log(getItemsAdded(arr3, arr4)); // [ 'q', 'r' ]
console.log(getItemsAdded(arr5, arr6)); // [ 'a', 'b', 'q' ]
// New
console.log(getItemsAdded(arr7, arr8)); // [ 'a', 'b' ]
```

It feels like such a simple problem, but I cant get my head around it.. I couldn't solve it with solutions provided here [How to get the difference between two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com), since its a different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code can tell more words, Then my silly explanation...

```js
// Input 1
const arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'];
const arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']; // added 'a' and 'b' in front
// Input 2
const arr3 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'];
const arr4 = ['q', 'r', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']; // added 'q' and 'r' in front
// Input 3
const arr5 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'];
const arr6 = ['a', 'b', 'q', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']; // added 'a' 'b' and 'q' in front

const arr7 = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
const arr8 = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']; // added 'a' and 'b'  in front

// Desired output for 'diff()' function
console.log([...getItemsAdded(arr1, arr2)]); // [ 'a', 'b' ]
console.log([...getItemsAdded(arr3, arr4)]); // [ 'q', 'r' ]
console.log([...getItemsAdded(arr5, arr6)]); // [ 'a', 'b', 'q' ]
console.log([...getItemsAdded(arr7, arr8)]); // [ 'a', 'b' ]

function startsWith(arr1, arr2) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
        if (arr1[i] != arr2[i])
            return false

    return true
}
function* getItemsAdded(arr1, arr2) {
    while (!startsWith(arr2, arr1)) yield arr2.shift()
}
```

Comment: You are my hero, even cases where one of the arrays is empty results in the correct output! Is this a well known method or did you had to come up with something?

Comment: I just remembered that how regex work,  It give me basic idea, how to implemented it...

Comment: I just got an unexpected output where I used `arr2` as the first input and added 'a' and 'b' again for the second output. Instead of the added items, it gives the entire new array as output.

Comment: I update my answer, In old answer, The problem is  `cmp`  function return index, where offset should get removed, this solution wouldn't work here, so we should remove 1 element at a time, Here, I also used generator for lazy evaluation.

Comment: I was trying myself by editing your previous solution, but couldn't figure it out myself. Thanks again! Now I just added a local array in `getItemsAdded` and fill it with the items returned by `arr2.shift()` and return this array instead of the generator.